# add_const or remove_const based on another type

Tags: c++, template, type-safety, casting, constants

Here is a type trait which - I feel - could fit in `std` next to [`std::add_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv) and [`std::remove_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct set_constness_of { 
    template <typename U>
    struct by {
        using type = typename std::conditional<
            std::is_const<U>::value,
            typename std::add_const<T>::type,
            typename std::remove_const<T>::type
            >::type;
    };
};
```

Note this is intentionally C++11 to minimize requirements for using it. One can obviously define `set_constness_of_t` in which `by` is a type rather than a struct with a type.

I've also written a tiny [sample program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/264f7c3ecf3aabee) (coliru.com) to ensure it runs, at least for some cases.

```
/* the above definition of set_constness_of goes here (paste it) */
#inlcude <iostream>  

struct foo {
    void m() { std::cout << "Non-const\n"; }
    void m() const { std::cout << "Const\n"; }
};

template <class T> void call_m() { T().m(); }

int main() {
    call_m<foo>();
    using bar = const int;
    call_m< set_constness_of<foo>::by<bar>::type >();
}
```

Questions:

- Is this correctly defined for all cases?
- What do you think about placing the second template parameter as an inner struct's template param, rather than having two template parameters on the outer struct?
- What do you think about the choice of naming?

Other comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any obvious omissions or bugs.

The naming and inner struct are neatly expressive (and remind me of some testing frameworks' precondition/assertion chaining).  It's not something that's done by the standard library, but I don't think it should be hugely controversial.

I might go with a naming like `copy_const<foo>::from<bar>` - or perhaps even the other way around: `copy_const<bar>::to<foo>`.  Or even both!  (Actually, I now wish `std::is_assignable` worked like that - it would be easier to remember which parameter is which!)

None of the above is a concrete suggestion - intended merely as food for thought!

Comment: If find the second version very fluent! Or maybe something like `constness_from<foo>::to<bar>`. There's a lot of valid option.  A strawpoll might be nice :p

Comment: `copy_const` sounds like "copy constructor"...

Comment: @Calak: See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Following @Calak's comment, I'm now thinking of the following change of order of the template parameters:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename U>
struct constness_of { 
    enum { value = std::is_const<U>::value };
    template <typename T>
    struct applied_to {
        using type = typename std::conditional<
            value,
            typename std::add_const<T>::type,
            typename std::remove_const<T>::type
            >::type;
    };
#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
    template <typename U>
    using applied_to_t = typename applied_to<U>::type;
#endif
};
```

Which would be used as follows:

```
if (constness_of<bar>::value) { std::cout << "bar is const!\n"; }
```

and:

```
using altered_foo = constness_of<bar>::applied_to<foo>::type;
using altered_foo_2 = constness_of<bar>::applied_to_t<foo>;
```

Comment: Not trying to be too annoying, but for copy-paste's sake, the member template inside the `#if` should have a different name for its typename, since U is already used.